# how to : specify a default action for a TYPO3 v4.5.30 extbase extension?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I made  a new extension in extension builder (a basic 4 model extension with no custom work in it, the only thing slightly fancy it does is extend the fe_users table) and installed it and made a page with the plugin and when I view the page I get a blank area where the plugin should appear - not a whole blank page just the part where the plugin should appear.  I put some `echo __FUNCTION__.__LINE__;die;` lines in all the listActions so if I was hitting any of them I'd at least know which I was hitting.  But I see no echo lines and I clearly never hit a die; so I guess my extension is not hitting any action, maybe because I have to specify one as the default. My extension has 4 models.  How do I specify what action gets called?  I am using typo3 v4.5.30 with extbase.

Thanks

PS: my ext_localconf file looks like so:

```
Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'mycore',
    array(
        'Player' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
        'Hall' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
        'Hallplayers' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
        'Hallvisits' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',

    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Player' => 'create, update, delete',
        'Hall' => 'create, update, delete',
        'Hallplayers' => 'create, update, delete',
        'Hallvisits' => 'create, update, delete',

    )
);
```

Comment: did you add a plugin as well ? It allows you to choose proper order of actions like `YourController=>list,show,edit` and if you did that it should work out of the box

Comment: in the ext builder?  that stuff is in my ext_localconf file already. When I add it in the builder it just limits things and I get the same behavior.  I bet there is some simple little thing I am forgetting to do in ext builder.  what about the frontend plugin key - why can't I use the same as my ext key?

Comment: ok, had to do several things in ext builder:  add a frontend plugin for each model, add the controllable actions and non-cacheable actions for each, point my page to one of the new plugins and remove the priority option "top" under the "more options" section.  now it works.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question: The first action defined in your plugin is automatic the default action. I never use 2 Actioncontroller in 1 plugin (Im not sure if that is even possible). If I have to change from 1 actioncontroller to another I use Fluid-Link:

```
<f:link.action pluginName="myOtherPlugin" pageUid="ThePageIDwhereThePluginShallBeCalled" action="TheActionOfThePlugin" controller="Controllername" arguments="{Modelname : Modelobject}">
```